# Difficulty with Razer Thunderbolt 4 Chroma dock on M1 MacBook Pro 13" (works on Intel MacBook Pro 16")

Tags: usb, thunderbolt, dock, apple-silicon

Summary:  my M1 MacBook Pro 13" can't see the SteelSeries APEX Pro keyboard or Rival 710 Gaming Mouse in my setup.  my Intel MacBook Pro 16" has no difficulty with them.

Systems:

M1 MacBook Pro 13" -- macOS 11.6
Intel MacBook Pro 16" -- macOS 11.6

External Display: Samsung C49RG9x (5120x1440@120Hz) connected via DisplayPort cable to a DisplayPort 1.4 output on KVM.
External Display USB Hub:
2xUSB3.x A (1 used for Logitech BRIO webcam)
2xUSB2.x A (1 used for SteelSeries APEX Pro keyboard, 1 for USB 2.0 passthrough from APEX with attached SteelSeries Rival 710 Gaming Mouse)
1 USB 3.x B connected via USB3.x B <--> A cable to USB3.x port on KVM.
Display connections are connected directly into my TRIPP-LITE DisplayPort 1.4 KVM 2x1 Switch (Product #: B005-DPUA2-K).

Thunderbolt 4 Dock 01: Razer Thunderbolt 4 Chroma connected to KVM machine 1 input via Maxonar USB-C <-> DisplayPort 1.4 cable (video) and USB 3.x A <-> A cable (provided with dock).

Machine 01: MacBook Pro 16" (2.6 GHz 6-Core Intel Core i7 / 16 GB DDR4 RAM) connected to B005-DPUA2-K machine 1 input via provided ThunderBolt 4 cable.

With Machine 01 connected, everything appears as expected.

Machine 02: MacBook Pro 13" (M1 / 16 GB DDR4 RAM) connected to same B005-DPUA2-K machine 1 input via Thunderbolt 4 cable provided with dock (also tried Apple Thunderbolt 3 cable with same results).

With Machine 02 connected instead, the C49RG9x display shows up as expected (5120x1440@120Hz), but the USB tree doesn't show the devices connected to the USB3.x hub included in the C49RG9x.

Aside from the different in the USB device tree output, I also noticed that on the Intel MBP, the Thunderbolt 4 dock shows up under Thunderbolt/USB on a bus in Thunderbolt 3 mode, while on the M1 MBP, the same dock shows up on a bus in USB4 mode.

Does anyone have any idea how to troubleshoot this further?  I'm thinking it's an issue with the M1 MBP, but am open to other suggestions.

-jb